# Jupyter Notebook Encoding Issue With Specific Kernel

Tags: python, pyspark, encoding, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook setup using AWS EMR which runs the notebook on the master node using docker containers.

There are 3 kernels available: (pyspark, python 3, spark)
[kernels screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtXxe.png)

Some simple code for testing the encoding issues below:
using kernel `pyspark`

```
%%pretty

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

print("哈哈")
```

Output is: `??`

using kernel `python 3`:

```
%matplotlib inline

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

print("哈哈")
```

Ouptut is: `哈哈`

Anyone has any idea what could be going wrong here?

Comment: The screenshot reveals nothing about how the Pyspark kernel is actually configured. Which Python version, any I/O encoding hacks or other shenanigans? Python 2 obviously had limited Unicode support.

Comment: Both kernels are running on Python 3.7 version.

Comment: Where should I be looking for those so called "encoding hacks"? Any hint?

Comment: Setting `PYTHONIOENCODING` in the environment or something like that. If encodings are broken, I guess that means you are on Windows, which would probably also be good to mention.

Comment: As mentioned, the setup was deployed on AWS EMR, which dockerized the jupyter-notebook on an EC2. Based on the dockerfile, I don't think it is a Windows environment. Tried `PYTHONIOENCODING`, it does not work as expected though.